Why does my bare-minimum app keeps restarting which was start with pm2?
I have a bare-minium app with only app.js, ecosystem and package.json file and nothing else. The app.js file contains only this:
class App {
    async init() {
        console.log('App started started');
    }
}

const app = new App();

app
    .init()
    .then()
    .catch(err => console.log('Error initializing app: ', err));

And the ecosystem file contains this:
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'main-app',
            script: './app.js',
            output: "./logs/app-out.log",
            error: "./logs/app-error.log",
            watch: false
        }
    ]
};

After I start the pm2 process with pm2 start, app keeps restarting. What could be the reason? I was facing this restart issue in my other app and so for testing I created this dummy, bare-minimum app and apparently it is happening here as well. Can someone shed some light?

That's the job of pm2. What else do you expect to happen?

@jabaa I dont understand. Why would it restart my app without any reason?

Why do you use pm2 if you don't want it to manage your app? pm2 is a process management tool. It restarts the app when it stops. https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/ "When starting application with PM2, applications are automatically restarted on auto exit"

Why would it manage my app like this? It should not restart the app without any reason.

That's the default restart strategy.

So you mean to say, it will keep on restarting without any reason until I pass --max-restart 0 flag?

Again: Why do you use pm2 at all, if you don't want its behavior? You can configure different restart strategies for pm2. If you don't want it to restart your app, either disable the auto restart, or don't use pm2 at all. I recommend reading the first 3 pages of the documentation.

You are not making any sense. My reason of using pm2 is not important here. My question is, I started a process and it shouldnt just restart withut any reason. I used it before. I have apps running on it. Never faced this. I have servers runnin on pm2. I really dont understand your point here. If i start an express server, you mean to say my server will keep on restarting without any reason?

"When starting application with PM2, applications are automatically restarted on auto exit, event loop empty (node.js) or when application crash." Yes, pm2 will restart your application. That's the default behavior if you don't configure a different restart strategy.

So in my bare-minimum app, it restarts because it has empty event loop or it is being 'auto exitter'?

The event loop is empty after app.init().then().catch(err => console.log('Error initializing app: ', err));. TBH, I'm not even sure, what's unclear here.

Make it a post so that i can close this

Your code is evaluated and the app exits after
app
    .init()
    .then()
    .catch(err => console.log('Error initializing app: ', err));

The event loop is empty. pm2 restarts the application. The default restart strategy is

When starting application with PM2, applications are automatically restarted on auto exit, event loop empty (node.js) or when application crash.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/
